# Create list from for loop if value in sequence is greater than .5

Tags: r

Trying to create a list of significant variables for a regression model. I have 82 variables, so in order to only include the significant ones, I created a list of the correlations and sorted them. I want to include the variables with correlations > 0.5 and <-0.5. I created a for loop, but am having difficulty getting a list.

composite is a data frame

```
sortedcor <- sort(cor(composite)[,1])
regvar = 0
for (i in sortedcor){
  if (sortedcor[i] < 0.5){
    regvar[] <- i
  }
}
```

getting this error:

Error in if (sortedcor[i] < 0.5) { : argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (sortedcor[i] < 0.5) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Check to make sure that `sortedcor[i]` is a single **numeric** value.

Comment: Also, should there be a index for `regvar[]` (i.e. something inside the brackets?)

Comment: I would like to have the names of the variables and their correlation coefficient. There shouldn't be anything inside regvar because it is an empty list that I was hoping to use the for loop to create. What is happening is it is putting the first value that satisfied the criteria (in this case, i get one value in regvar that is 0.483) and the loop seems to stop. I went to cycle over all of sortedcor and get each value that is >0.5, and also those that are less than -0.5, and get the corresponding names so I can add their names to my lm() formula, since these are the significant variables.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but trying the following ``> regvar = 0
> regvar[] = 2
> regvar[] = 3
> regvar
[1] 3
`` just gives 3 which isn't a list.

Comment: But beyond that point, what does sortedcor look like?  I assume its a vector or sorted correlations?

Comment: To fix it, I believe you just need to change it to `for (i in 1:length(sortedcor)){`

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code doing what you want.  You will need to modify what `sortcor` in my code is to match yours.

```
#Create some example correlation values
correlations = runif(100,-1,1)

#Don't need to sort but I'll do it anyway to follow your logic
sortcor = sort(correlations)

#Create an empty vector to hold the parameters of interest
regvar = NULL

k = 1
for(i in 1:length(sortcor)){
    if(sortcor[i] > .5 | sortcor[i] < -.5){
        regvar[k] = i
        k = k+1
    }
}
```

so now `regvar` is a vector of indexes corresponding to the parameters of the regression model that have correlation bigger than 0.5 or less that -0.5.  Note that I sorted the correlations like you did but really you don't need to if you don't sort the parameters of your model as well.